# How to indicate that date is null in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the following code I was hoping to retrieve the records that have a null value for the ClosedDateTimeT field, but it only shows the records that have a value. Am I doing something wrong here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.ticketid,
    t.Sub,
    i.status, 
    i.OwnedByTeam,
    i.OwnedByTeamT,
    i.TypeOptions,
    i.ClosedDateTimeT,
    i.CompletedDateTime,
    i.TitleT 
FROM
    ticket AS t 
INNER JOIN
    Incident AS i ON t.TicketID = i.IncidentID
WHERE
    CAST(t.Sub AS DATE) >= '01-01-2019' 
    AND CAST(t.Sub AS DATE ) <= '05-30-2019'
    AND i.Subcategory = 'Content Request'
    AND (i.TypeOptions = 'New/Initial Submission' OR
         i.TypeOptions = 'Am/Re')
    AND ((i.OwnedByTeamT LIKE '%C - CA%' 
          AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%' 
          AND i.ClosedDateTimeT IS NOT NULL) OR
         (i.OwnedByTeamT LIKE '%C - CA%'
          AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%'
          AND i.ClosedDateTimeT IS NULL) OR
         (i.OwnedByTeamT LIKE '%E - Cl%' 
          AND i.TitleT LIKE '%OP B V%'))
```

Comment: Could you please format your code before you post (or after by [edit]ing it)? It would be much easier to read this way. Finally please include sample input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @lgor sure, working on it.

Comment: You have some interesting predicates going on here. The first two i.OwnedByTeamT are rather bizarre. Why do you have two predicates there? The first one checks if ClosedDateTimeT is null and the second if it is not null.

Comment: place i.ClosedDateTimeT is null predicate outside of an OR condition

Comment: It's only null if i.OwnedByTeamT like '%C - CA%' and AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%' conditions are met. Is that the way you wanted, if so then make sure that scenario exists.

Comment: @bvmcode, No. What I want is that if OwnedByTeamT like '%C - CA%' and AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%'  tell me if the value for closeddatetime is null (meaning the task for that team is still open). If it has a vale, meaning the task is closed, show it to me too.

Comment: I think you can just remove i.ClosedDateTimeT from your WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your comments I would remove just remove that date field from your where clause. I also removed a piece that repeated i.OwnedByTeamT like '%C - CA%' AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%'

```
Select distinct t.ticketid,
 t.Sub,
 i.status, 
 i.OwnedByTeam,
 i.OwnedByTeamT,
 i.TypeOptions,
 i.ClosedDateTimeT,
 i.CompletedDateTime,
 i.TitleT 

From ticket as t inner join Incident as i on  
t.TicketID=i.IncidentID

where 
CAST(t.Sub AS DATE) >= '01-01-2019' 
AND CAST(t.Sub AS DATE ) <= '05-30-2019'
AND i.Subcategory = 'Content Request'
AND (i.TypeOptions='New/Initial Submission' OR
 i.TypeOptions='Am/Re')
AND (
(i.OwnedByTeamT like '%C - CA%' AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%' 
)
OR (
i.OwnedByTeamT like '%E - Cl%' AND i.TitleT LIKE '%OP B V%')
)
```

Comment: can you please explain why my code didn't work, logically it should have worked, right?

Comment: The first two sets of parantheses in that AND clause conflicted with each other. The first one won out. No need to restrict a field in WHERE if you are not looking for it to be restriced.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what the issue is you are facing but your query could be simplified a bit and formatted. Notice I also am using ANSI compliant date literals.

```
Select distinct t.ticketid
    , t.Sub
    , i.status
    , i.OwnedByTeam
    , i.OwnedByTeamT
    , i.TypeOptions
    , i.ClosedDateTimeT
    , i.CompletedDateTime
    , i.TitleT 
From ticket as t 
inner join Incident as i on t.TicketID=i.IncidentID
where 
    CAST(t.Sub AS DATE) >= '20190101' 
    AND CAST(t.Sub AS DATE ) <= '20190530'
    AND i.Subcategory = 'Content Request'
    AND i.TypeOptions in ('New/Initial Submission', 'Am/Re')
    AND 
    (
        (
            i.OwnedByTeamT like '%C - CA%' 
            AND 
            i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%'
        )
        OR
        (
            i.OwnedByTeamT like '%E - Cl%' 
            AND 
            i.TitleT LIKE '%OP B V%'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ticketid
    ,t.Sub
    ,i.STATUS
    ,i.OwnedByTeam
    ,i.OwnedByTeamT
    ,i.TypeOptions
    ,i.ClosedDateTimeT
    ,i.CompletedDateTime
    ,i.TitleT
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN Incident AS i ON t.TicketID = i.IncidentID
WHERE i.ClosedDateTimeT IS NULL
    AND CAST(t.Sub AS DATE) >= '01-01-2019'
    AND CAST(t.Sub AS DATE) <= '05-30-2019'
    AND i.Subcategory = 'Content Request'
    AND (
        i.TypeOptions = 'New/Initial Submission'
        OR i.TypeOptions = 'Am/Re'
        )
    AND (
        (
            i.OwnedByTeamT LIKE '%C - CA%'
            AND i.TitleT LIKE '%B Build%'
            )
        OR (
            i.OwnedByTeamT LIKE '%E - Cl%'
            AND i.TitleT LIKE '%OP B V%'
            )
        )
```

Comment: I want to be able to pick the CloseddatetimeT dates regardless of their value. For example, if the date is null, meaning the task is not closed, show it to me. Also, if it has a value, meaning the task is closed, show it as well!

Comment: then why have it in the where clause at all?